# how can i solve this poblem of import?

Tags: android-studio, button, import

[image]

Can you tell me the reason why i can't import:

```
import android.widget.Button
```

I don't know why I can't import. I wasted much time because of this problem.

please help me!! it's first time to use android-studio

Comment: Import statement is showing in gray means you are importing ```Button``` but not using it in class so once you will use Button in class it will turn out from gray to white as other imports